# ASP.net MVC - Telerik Reporting error => /api/reports/clients returns "Missing report name"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, reportviewer

I am new to Telerik Reporting & have started adding Report Viewer to my ASP.net MVC application. In runtime ReportViewer is displaying "Bad Request" & Fiddler is displaying below error message.

**Message:**
POST /api/reports/clients/215829-979c/parameters HTTP/1.1
"Missing report name"

Can you please help me in this.

Report viewer code snippet:

```
Html.TelerikReporting().ReportViewer()
                   .Id("reportViewer1")
                   .ServiceUrl("/api/reports")
                   .TemplateUrl("/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate.html")
                   .ReportSource(Model.ReportSource)
                   .ViewMode(ViewModes.INTERACTIVE)
                   .ScaleMode(ScaleModes.SPECIFIC)
                   .Scale(1.0)
```

thank you
-nm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are passing the report in from the controller, as that code is not in your post, but you may want to troubleshoot by directly referencing your report's assembly name as follows (replace "Application" with your root namespace):

```
@{
var typeReportSource = new TypeReportSource() { TypeName = "Application.Reports.Report1, Application" };
}
@(
Html.TelerikReporting().ReportViewer()
   .Id("reportViewer1")
   .ServiceUrl("/api/reports/")
   .TemplateUrl("/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate.html")
   .ReportSource(typeReportSource)
   .ViewMode(ViewModes.PRINT_PREVIEW)
   .ScaleMode(ScaleModes.SPECIFIC)
   .Scale(1.0)
   .PersistSession(true)
)
```